# c++ conflict of the copy constructor and return temp object

Tags: c++

```
  1 #include <iostream>
  2 #include <cmath>
  3 
  4 using namespace std;
  5 
  6 class complx
  7 {
  8 private:
  9     double real;
 10     double imag;
 11 public:
 12     complx() {}
 13     complx(double r, double i): real(r), imag(i) {}
 14     complx(complx &c) {real = c.real; imag = c.imag;}
 15     complx operator + (const complx &c) const
 16     {
 17         return complx(real + c.real, imag + c.imag);
 18     }
 19 
 20     complx & operator=(const complx & c)
 21     {
 22         real = c.real;
 23         imag = c.imag;
 24 
 25         return *this;
 26     }
 27 
 28     friend ostream& operator << (ostream &os, const complx &c);
 29 
 30     double size() const
 31     {
 32         return sqrt(real*real + imag*imag);
 33     }
 34 };
 35 
 36 ostream & operator << (ostream &os, const complx &c)
 37 {
 38     os << "(" << c.real << "," << c.imag << ")";
 39 
 40     return os;
 41 }
 42 
 43 const complx & maximum(const complx &c1, const complx &c2)
 44 {
 45     if (c1.size() > c2.size())
 46     {
 47         return c1;
 48     }
 49     else
 50     {
 51         return c2;
 52     }
 53 }
 54 
 55 
 56 int main(void)
 57 {
 58     complx c1(10, 30);
 59     complx c2(13, 25);
 60     complx mx = maximum(c1, c2);
 61 
 62     cout << c1 << endl;
 63     return 0;
 64 }
```

I don't know what's wrong with this code, it could not pass the compile. Only if I annotate line 14(the copy constructor) or rewrite line 17 to return a concrete object, it will pass the compile and run correctly.

Comment: Style hint: Copy constructors are a type of constructors, and have initializer lists as well.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `complx(complx &c)` will not bind to a temporary. To fix, you should redefine it as:

`complx(const complx &c);`

One more suggestion: use initializer lists, or better yet, forward other constructors to the one constructing from raw values:

```
complx(complx &c) {real = c.real; imag = c.imag;}
```

should be:

```
complx(complx &c): complx(c.real, c.imag) {}
```

Comment: Thank you. really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The copy constructor should take a const parameter, to ensure that you are not going to change the parameter's attributes inside the body of the constructor then your constuctor's signature should be `classname (const classname &obj)`

Comment: Thank you. really appreciate it.